# Set time string on tick labels

Tags: slider, linechart

This is not working for me in JavaFX. I would like to use time format on tick labels for Slider and LineChart, none is working.

```
Slider slider;
    String sliderMin = "12:30:22";
    String sliderMax = "13:20:43";
    double sliderDoubleMin = Double.parseDouble(sliderMin);
    double sliderDoubleMax = Double.parseDouble(sliderMax);
    slider.setMin(sliderDoubleMin);
    slider.setMax(sliderDoubleMax);
```

How can I get this to work?

It can handle numbers like "400" but not in time format. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javafx slider: text as tick label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447963/javafx-slider-text-as-tick-label)

Comment: Thanks Perfect helped a lot!